# Extracting move information from a pgn file on Python

Tags: python, chess

How do I go about extracting move information from a pgn file on Python? I'm new to programming and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So far I can return a string of the moves in this form:
'1.e4 c6 2.d3 d5 3.Nd2 e5 4.Ngf3 Nd7 5.d4 dxe4 6.Nxe4 exd4 7.Qxd4 Ngf6 8.Bg5 Be7...etc
What I need to do now is to return a string that summarises the information in the movetext in this form: "White move the pawn at e2 to e4.\nBlack moved the pawn at e7 to e5."

Comment: Also, for some files the string is being returned in this form: 
'1. e4 e5 2. f4 exf4 3. Nf3 g5 4. h4 g4 5. Ne5 Nf6 6. d4 d6 7. Nd3 Nxe4...etc There is a space after the move number.

Answer (score 10):

Try [pgnparser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pgnparser/1.0).

Example code:

```
import pgn
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
pgn_text = f.read()
f.close()
games = pgn.loads(pgn_text)
for game in games:
    print game.moves
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted answer. It's been six years but this answer has helped me because I was facing the exact same dilemma of not knowing which parser to use for going through my png file, particularly with how sparse the official documentation is.

Answer (score 6):

@Dennis Golomazov
I like what Denis did above. To add on to what he did, if you want to extract move information from more than 1 game in a png file, say like in games in chess database png file, use chess.pgn.

```
import chess.pgn 
png_folder = open('sample.pgn')
current_game = chess.pgn.read_game(png_folder)
png_text = str(current_game.mainline_moves())
```

read_game() method acts as an iterator so calling it again will grab the next game in the pgn.

Comment: I think it should be `current_game.mainline_moves()`

Comment: Good find. Just changed it

Answer (score 4):

I can't give you any Python-specific directions, but I wrote a PGN converter recently in java, so I'll try offer some advice. The main disadvantage of Miku's link is the site doesn't allow for variance in .pgn files, which every site seems to vary slightly on the exact format.

1. Some .pgn have the move number attached to the move itself (1.e4 instead of 1. e4) so if you tokenise the string, you could check the placement of the dot since it only occurs in move numbers.
2. Work out all the different move combinations you can have. If a move is 5 characters long it could be 0-0-0 (queenside castles), Nge2+ (Knight from g to e2 with check(+)/ checkmate(#)), Rexb5 (Rook on e takes b5).
3. The longest string a move could be is 7 characters (for when you must specify origin rank AND file AND a capture AND with check). The shortest is 2 characters (a pawn advance).
4. Plan early for castling and en passant moves. You may realise too late that the way you have built your program doesn't easily adapt for them.
5. The details given at the start(ELO ratings, location, etc.) vary from file to file.

Answer (score 4):

I dont have PGN parser for python but You can get source code of PGN parser for XCode from [this place](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/05/pgn-file-parser-in-objective-c-for-use.html) it can be of assistance